# I need to sort by the most changed GROUP by in a table

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table called EssayStats with three columns, EssayDate, WordCount and EssayId.

Each row is a record of when the bot recorded how many words were in an essay at a particular point in time.

I'm trying to write a query that will group by EssayId and sort by the largest increase in WordCount from a particular EssayDate to an ending EssayDate.

I'm not really sure where to start. I've tried a handful of things but they obviously don't accomplish what I jeed. My most recent query attempt was

```
SELECT *
FROM EssayStats
WHERE EssayDate >= "2014-01-01" AND EssayDate <= "2014-05-31"
GROUP BY EssayId
ORDER BY (WordCount)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by getting the dates at the beginning and end for each essay.  Then `join` back the original tables to get the counts and do some arithmetic:

```
select es.EssayId, (esmax.WordCount - esmin.WordCount)
from (select es.EssayId, min(es.EssayDate) as mined, max(es.EssayDate) as maxed
      from EssayStats es
      group by es.EssayId
     ) es join
     EssayStats esmin
     on es.EssayId = esmin.EssayId and es.mined = esmin.EssayDate join
     EssayStats esmax
     on es.EssayId = esmax.EssayId and es.maxed = esmax.EssayDate;
```